# Messages in Error List in Visual Studio 2017

Tags: asp.net

I am using bootstrap in Visual Studio 2017.  Specially, I am using it on some ASP controls.  Like so:

```
<asp:Button ID="btnSave" runat="server" Text="Register" class="btn btn-primary btn-md" OnClientClick="return ValidatePage();" OnClick="btnSave_Click">
```

I am curious about using attributes that don't apply to specific ASP object to apply bootstrap setting to the ASP object.  In this example, I use the attribute class on the ASP button object.  Only pops a message in the VS error list but I have seen VS get a little "side-ways" when too many seemly benign errors pop-up.

Answer (score 2):

You should be using the `CssClass` attribute for this.

```
<asp:Button ID="btnSave" runat="server" CssClass="btn btn-primary btn-md"
```

Then you can set/update it from code behind also.

```
btnSave.CssClass = "btn btn-primary btn-md";
```